# Setting button up/down on mouse move (PyQt6)

Tags: python, pyqt6

What I'm trying to achieve is Button that appears pressed down when user presses left mouse button, but activates only when mouse button is released when cursor is still over that button area. I want that behavior only for left mouse button while right button should do something else.

So I wrote this code:

```
class MyButton(QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        ...some code...
    
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.MouseButton.LeftButton :
            self.setDown(True)
            self.pressed.emit()
        if event.button() == Qt.MouseButton.RightButton :
            ...do something else...
    
    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.MouseButton.LeftButton :
            if event.pos() in self.rect():
                self.clicked.emit()
    
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        print('debug:', event.button())
        if event.pos() in self.rect():
            self.setDown(True)
        else:
            self.setDown(False)
```

I don't want button to be set up/down when moving mouse around with right button pressed, but i cannot use `if event.button() == Qt.MouseButton.LeftButton :` because on mouse move `event.button()` returns `NoButton` (see debug line). Any Ideas?

Comment: You must use [`buttons()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qmouseevent.html#buttons) in mouse move events. As the documentation explains, `button()` **returns the button that caused the event**: mouse move events are *not* caused by mouse buttons.